# How to change EAP method in hostapd?

Tags: networking, wifi, hostapd, 802.1x, wpa2-eap

I've seen that `hostapd` support a lot of EAP methods.

But it's not clear to me how I can switch to one of these methods.

I've checked in the `.conf` file but I honestly don't know which parameter I need to change.

Thank you.